# MongoDB with Mongoose aggregate data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have problems with aggregating data:

//create a schema

```
var userSchema = new Schema (
    { 
        Anzahl: Number,
        Art: String,
        Gewicht: Number,
        Strecken_ID: Number,
    },  {collection: 'kkr'});
```

//model

```
var User = db.model('User', userSchema);
```

//test aggregate

```
app.get('/gesamt', function(req,res){

    User.aggregate([{"$match": {Art: "Aal"}}], function(err, docs){

            if(err){console.log(err);}
            else {res.json(docs);}
    });

});
```

This delivers an empty array []; what ist the reason?

Any help would be great.

Best

Hucho

Comment: Check the collection named 'kkr' in your MongoDB(use `mongo` client command line or other MongoDB clients). If there are no documents with attribute `Art` equals to `Aal`, then you got an empty array naturally.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem...data was different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` means there is no documents with value `Art: "Aal"` in `kkr` collection.

Comment: I could not believe it first; but then I checked my mongo data again...and you were right; there was a problem in the columns which resulted in values other than I was looking for. Thank you for making me see in the right direction!